# How to get contents of frames automatically if browser does not support frames + can't access frame directly

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to automatically download PDFs from URLs like [this](http://www.un.org/en/ga/search/view_doc.asp?symbol=A/RES/68/278) to make a library of UN resolutions.

If I use beautiful soup or mechanize to open that URL, I get "Your browser does not support frames" -- and I get the same thing if I use the copy as curl feature in chrome dev tools.

The standard advice for the "Your browser does not support frames" when using mechanize or beautiful soup is to follow the source of each individual frame and load that frame. But if I do so, I get to an error message that the page is not [authorized](http://daccess-ods.un.org/access.nsf/Get?Open&DS=A/RES/68/278&Lang=E).

How can I proceed? I guess I could try this in zombie or phantom but I would prefer to not use those tools as I am not that familiar with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, this was an interesting task to do with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

There is a set of underlying calls to `un.org` and `daccess-ods.un.org` that are important and set relevant cookies. This is why you need to maintain [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) and visit several urls before getting access to the pdf.

Here's the complete code:

```
import re
from urlparse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


BASE_URL = 'http://www.un.org/en/ga/search/'
URL = "http://www.un.org/en/ga/search/view_doc.asp?symbol=A/RES/68/278"
BASE_ACCESS_URL = 'http://daccess-ods.un.org'

# start session
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(URL, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36'})

# get frame links
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
frames = soup.find_all('frame')
header_link, document_link = [urljoin(BASE_URL, frame.get('src')) for frame in frames]

# get header
session.get(header_link, headers={'Referer': URL})

# get document html url
response = session.get(document_link, headers={'Referer': URL})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

content = soup.find('meta', content=re.compile('URL='))['content']
document_html_link = re.search('URL=(.*)', content).group(1)
document_html_link = urljoin(BASE_ACCESS_URL, document_html_link)

# follow html link and get the pdf link
response = session.get(document_html_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

# get the real document link
content = soup.find('meta', content=re.compile('URL='))['content']
document_link = re.search('URL=(.*)', content).group(1)
document_link = urljoin(BASE_ACCESS_URL, document_link)
print document_link

# follow the frame link with login and password first - would set the important cookie
auth_link = soup.find('frame', {'name': 'footer'})['src']
session.get(auth_link)

# download file
with open('document.pdf', 'wb') as handle:
    response = session.get(document_link, stream=True)

    for block in response.iter_content(1024):
        if not block:
            break

        handle.write(block)
```

You should probably extract separate blocks of code into functions to make it more readable and reusable.

FYI, all of this could be more easily done through the real browser with the help of [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) of [`Ghost.py`](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When you mentioned `Ghost.py` at the end, did you mean `GhostDriver`? Because I googled and didn't find much about how to combine selenium and Ghost.py. Could you provide more information?