# How to access the body inside a <frameset> tag using requests.get() method?

Tags: python, html, authentication, python-requests

I am trying to log in to http://biis.buet.ac.bd/ using python requests module.
but it seems it has a frameset tag at the top of its structure and i can't seem to get the body inside the frameset tag. my code is:

```
headers={
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Mobile 
Safari/537.36"
}

with requests.session() as s:
    URL = "http://biis.buet.ac.bd/"
    gr=s.get(url=URL,headers=headers)
    print(gr.content)
```

Here it is only giving a output:

```
<html>\n<HEAD>\n</HEAD>\n<FRAMESET cols="0%, 100%">\n  <FRAME src="left.html" noresize>\n  <FRAME 
src="right.html" noresize>\n</FRAMESET>\n\n</html>\n'
```

how do i access the body inside the frame?

Comment: check the api, it is calling one html file <FRAME src="left.html", you need to call this in another request to get the response.

Comment: couldn't find anything related to FRAME in the documentation of requests module
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/search/?q=frame

Comment: check this : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841632/how-to-get-contents-of-frames-automatically-if-browser-does-not-support-frames](link)